# Search results showing old title in renamed file

Tags: search, enterprise-search

I have renamed a document title and file name in a document library and I'm using content search webpart which I use to show the results.

The issue is the search results are returning both the new document and the document with old title. I have ran both incremental crawl and full crawl but the results are same.

How to clear the old document title from showing up in search results. Is it possible to delete the result from search index using a powershell or via UI in central admin search administration.

Comment: Did you make sure this document is published as a major version instead of a draft?

Answer (score 0):

In the search SSA you can remove a search result from the index if you have the URL to the item.

Comment: did you mean "Search results removal"?

Comment: Yes I did. Did that work for you?

Comment: I did a index reset and this fixed the issue. I had issue resetting index and fixed it as mentioned in this article http://www.thetugboatcomplex.com/?p=1102... but that led to another issue :)

Comment: That's a pretty drastic solution. I hope you don't have a lot of content.

Comment: I have less than 1M content.